# iPhone App Submission Question

Tags: iphone, xcode, project

In my Xcode project I put all my images, audio files, ect... in the resources folder. When I opened the project folder in finder all of my "resources" are not in a resources folder instead they are just scattered in the main folder (I have a good number of files).

I already submitted the binary to Apple on Friday so will they care if the "resources" were in the main project folder? Everything works, I'm just paranoid, and since its only been a day should I just resubmit a fixed binary or not worry?

I noticed when creating a project in Xcode from one of the preset templates no designated resources folder is created within the project folder. So I'm figuring it's okay, just want to be safe and not sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 4):

Resources are copied into an application's .app bundle at build time. It doesn't matter where they're initially stored on disk. You're safe!

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the application, resources are copied into the .app bundle automatically. This can be overridden by modifying the target build directives, if I recall correctly. Generally, if you don't know if those settings have been modified, you should be fine.